# How can I convert distance to pixels on a R leaflet map?

Tags: r, leaflet

I would like to extract the size of polygons **in pixels** from a leaflet map in R.

Currently, I am using sf polygons to create the polygons on the leaflet map. Ideally, I would like to capture the **distance from the polygon centroid to the closest point** **on the polygon** **in pixels**. This R code calculates this distance in spatial units (meters) rather than pixels: `sf::st_length(sf::st_nearest_points(polygon, centroid))` .

Ideally, there would be some function that returns this distance in pixels for every polygon on the leaflet map.

Example starting code:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# loading spatial data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) |>
  sf::st_transform("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

polytest <- nc[1,15]

# Creating leaflet map with polygons and markers
m <- leaflet::leaflet() |>
  leaflet::addPolygons(data = polytest,
              fillOpacity = 0,
              color = "red",
              weight = 1)
```